# linked list C++ , question selflearning

Tags: c++, linked-list, self

```
        #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;



    struct Node
    {
        int item;   // storage for the node's item
        Node* next;   // pointer to the next node 
    };

  Node* addNode(Node*& head, int data , int& count) 
{
    Node * q;     // new node
    q = new Node;  // allocate memory for the new mode
    q->item = data;  // inserting data for the new node
    q->next = head;   // point to previous node ?? how would i do that? ( am i doing it correctly?)
    count++; // keep track of number of node
    head = q;
    return q;
}



    int main()
    {
        int a, count=0;
        int data;
        bool repeat;
        Node *head= NULL;   
        //^^ assuming thats creating the first node ^^
        do
        {
        cout << "please enter the data for the next node" <<endl;
        cin >> data;
        addNode(head, data, count);
        cout << "do you wish to enter another node? (enter true or false)" << endl;
        cin >>repeat;
        }
       while (repeat == true);


       // assuming this is the print function  
          while(head != NULL)
        {
            cout << "output" << temp->item << endl;
            cout << temp->next << endl;
        }

        system("pause");
        return 0; 
    }
```

okey i tried adding a new element in the list how would i move the head around like a LIFO memory (stack) so the last element is on the very top..

any help would be appreciated ! The pointers and the nodes are messing with my brain lately ....

Comment: To use the code button `{}` you must select all the code.

Comment: Please use more appropriate language next time.

Comment: a simple google search could showed you a lot of C++ already-done examples

Comment: im trying to do it myself so i know how to do it from scratch

Comment: updated ... tried to put everything in a function

Comment: You still do not allocate the memory for temp. Replace `Node *temp;` with `Node *temp = new Node();` and your initialization should be fine. You did not show us the `addNode`-function. However, it can not work, as you do not submit the pointer (or better: a pointer to the pointer) to the head to this function. Thus, the function will not know where to find the list.

Comment: @Thilo i mess up the edit and overwrite it with the old one ... let me fix that just for you!

Comment: Now this looks alright for me. What does not work exactly? Note that you do not clean up your allocated memory, causing memory leaks in the process. Furthermore, your print part of the program will result in an endless loop, as head is not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not sure every answer completely answers it, here's a linked list implementation (written without testig:

```
// your (correct) structure
struct Node
{
    float item;   // storage for the node's item
    Node* next;   // pointer to the next node 
};
```

Now we need two pointers somewhere to look after the list:

```
/* some pointers */
struct List
{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
};
```

Now we need to create  some elements. As others have said, you can do that with new:

```
/* create some elements we want to link in */
Node* elem1 = new Node();
Node* elem2 = new Node();
Node* elem3 = new Node();
/* maybe even set their properties! */
elem1->item = 3.14;
elem2->item = 3.14;
elem3->item = 3.14;
```

Notice how I didn't try to add these elements to a list yet? That's because I've got a function in mind which looks like this:

```
void addtolist(List &list, Node* node)
{
    /* if no head, initialise the list */
    if ( list->head == NULL )
    {
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }
    else if ( list->head != NULL && list->tail != NULL )
    {
        /* access the tail element and set its 
           next to this ptr. 
           Move tail to this node */
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }
    else
    {
        /* probably raise an exception! */
    }
}
```

You can call this by doing this:

```
List l;
addtolist(l, elem1); /* etc */
```

Deleting elements is somewhat more tricky, since you have to go to that element, remember its previous element, grab it's next element, join them up and delete the Node* you're on.

Now for traversing lists... your terminology `HEAD|TAIL` reminds me of Erlang and tail recursion, where the current element is referred to as the head and the remainder the tail. If I write:

```
Node* cur = l.head;
while ( cur != NULL )
{
    // do something with cur.item ? 
    cur = cur->next;
}
```

You can see this happening. Replacing `cur` with `head` here would be harmless thanks to the `List` struct.

Finally, I've used a very C-like approach here, but there's scope for templates:

```
template<typename T>
struct node
{
    T item;   // storage for the node's item
    Node<T>* next;   // pointer to the next node 
};
```

and encapsulating the `List` struct as a class:

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
protected:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
public:

    void addtolist(Node<T>* node);
    Node<T>* gethead();
    Node<T>* gettail();
}
```

Which brings you a little bit closer to `std::list`.

Comment: very nice explanation but ill do it literately i hate recursive. recursive keep messing with my brain...

Comment: @ricedragon that particular piece of code is **not** recursion. Recursion involves using functions. It's just you've used very similar terminology to the Erlang idea of tail recursion on lists. But that while loop is not recursion, it's just constantly looking up the next item.

Comment: @Ninefingure i was studying recursive a bit earlier today yeah i realized that no. But this is the first time i see the tail and head in a new node. I'm still a beginner ill stick with the basic for now ty for your reply

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is an uninitialized pointer. So -

```
temp-> item = a;  // temp is not initialized or pointing to a memory location
                  // that has Node object to use operator ->
```

First, `temp` needs to be allocated memory location using `new`.

```
temp = new Node;
temp -> item = a;
```

And now assign it `head`. Similarly allocate memory for the child nodes too in the `while` loop. And return all the resources acquired from child to head using `delete` before program termination.

Comment: oh my bad i was doing it on the fly didnt pay attention to the data types

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some misunderstandings here:

Your "head" is the start of the list. It's always the start.

You <strike>add</strike> append elements to a linked list by assigning them to the last node's `next` pointer.

Third, you're not allocating anything.

```
Node *head= new Node();   
Node *temp = new Node();
cout<<"enter something into data"<<endl;
cin >> a ;
temp->item = a;
head->next = temp;
```

Now ... to add the next thing, you either need to keep track of the last node (tail), or traverse the list to find the last node.

```
Node *nextNode = new Node();
nextNode->item = 0.0;
Node *i;
for (i = head; i->next != null; i = i->next);
i->next = nextNode;
```

This is O(n) execution time. By keeping track of the tail you make it O(1):

```
Node *head= new Node();
Node *tail = head;   
Node *temp = new Node();
cout<<"enter something into data"<<endl;
cin >> a ;
temp->item = a;
tail->next = temp;
tail = temp;

Node *nextNode = new Node();
nextNode->item = 0.0;
tail->next = nextNode;
tail = nextNode;
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out, if you want to prepend to the list, you would:

```
temp->next = head;
head = temp;
```

Comment: I disagree. If you would repeat your code, you would create memory leaks, as you override the item at <code>head->next</code> multiple times. Ricedragon did it mostly correct, as he inserts at the start of the list and afterwards sets the head to the new value. This is basically std::list's push_front(). Edit: Sorry, did not see your last sentence at the first go. However, I still do think Ricedragons way works, except the missing allocation.

Comment: I agree with you if you want `push` functionality. I was describing appending ::shrug:: depends on what you're looking for. Back in the day I always just kept track of the tail to make it easy to do that.

Comment: @Thilo i modify the original code a bit and couldn't figure it out on how to add new elements  to the head. 
@Brian Roach ty this helps a lot i seem to get the head and tail  now i added new code ( a modify of the original one can you please take a look at it? )

Answer (score 0):

Additionally note that you are doing an implicit cast from `int` to `float` on

```
temp-> item = a;
```

as `a` is an `int`, while `temp->item` is a `double`.

To solve your problem: You want to allocate a new structure before accessing `temp`, thus

```
temp = new Node();
```

Comment: okey ill try it out and then post back if i have more problems